# Is constructing a function that DNE a sufficient counterexample to show the function does not diverge to $\infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

Prove or disprove: If $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a^+$ and $g(x)\geq 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then $g(x)/f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to a^+$.

Counterexample: Let $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Clearly, $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a^+$ and $g(x)\geq 1$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, but $g(x)/f(x)=1/0$ does not exist for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and thus cannot diverge to $\infty$ as $x\to a^+$.

Question: Is purposefully constructing a function in this manner a sufficient counterexample? Why or why not?

Comment: Ask the instructor (if it is homework).  Or, ask yourself what you will use it for (if not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably this is not a counterexample.  One, fairly reasonable, way to interpret $$\lim_{x\to a+} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=\infty$$ to avoid the problem of $0$ in the denominator is that for all $M$, there is some $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $x\in(a,a+\epsilon]$ $\color{blue}{\textrm{where the fraction is defined}}$, $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}>M$.  In your example, the fraction is never defined, and hence for any $\epsilon$ the property holds vacuously.